# proportion question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A contractor agrees to lay a road $3000$ metres long in $30$ days. $50$ men are employed and they work $8$ hours a day. After $20$ working days he finds that only $1200$ metres of the road is completed. How many more men does he need to employ in order to finish the project on time if each man now works $10$ hours a day?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:** think in terms of rate of work. How many meters can one man lay in one hour? Find this by looking at the work already done.

Then look at the work still to be done. Use that and the rate of work to find how many man-hours are still needed. Then find how many more men are needed.

To get more hints than that you will need to show us that you have done some work of your own on the problem.

Comment: 50 men 8 hrs a day, 20 day, 20*8=160, each men160 hrs of work for 20 days, total working hours 160*50=8000. 1200/8000 =0.15m for every working hour?

Comment: @linwei: Yes, that is right. You have now used my first hint and answered my first question. Now keep going. The very next thing to calculate is the number of meters remaining, then the number of man-hours remaining.

Comment: i have all the working u are talking about what i need is to show it in direct/indirect proportion

Comment: @linwei: I thought the proportion was obvious. We are talking about "rate of work" and "man-hours" because the work done is directly proportional to the number of hours worked and also to the number of men working. This proportion leads us to an equation with a constant, and that constant is the rate of work with the unit meters per man-hour. We could also say that the number of men needed is inversely proportional to the number of hours. If you needed an answer that explicitly uses proportions, you should have said so in your question.

Comment: ohhhhh now i get it thanks alot this is a new topic so it takes some time for me to realize the difference  anyways thanks alot